# how to clean files compiled by cython extensions

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I have few `cython` extensions that are built using `setuptools`:

```
python setup.py build
```

I would have expected that they were removed calling:

```
python setup.py clean --all
```

but they are not, do you have a suggestion on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

(I am not sure if it is what you want) Do you want to delete the files generated?

```
FileIO.purge(Path.currentPath() , r".*\.c$")
FileIO.purge(Path.currentPath() , r".*\.pyd$")
FileIO.purge(Path.currentPath() , r".*\.pyc$")

def purge(path, pattern):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        filename = re.search(pattern, f) 
        if filename is None:
            pass
        else:
            os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```